# The most elegant way to locate two enums

Tags: java, console, enum

I have situation where user has got options to select, and after selected any option will appear next options. For example :
1 - Add car
2 - Add motorcycle.
3 - Print cars
4 - Print motorcycles

And after selected for example "1" console will show options like : 
1 - Add passenger car,
2 - Add light commercial car. 
At this moment i have two enum classes in two separated files that has got almost the same code inside, and same methods `createFromInt()` which returns Options according to int provided by the user, and `toString()`.Exmple one of two enums(The second one is almost the same except the fields) :

```
enum Option {
ADD_CAR(0,"Add car"),
ADD_MOTORCYCLE(1,"Add motorcycle"),
PRINT_CARS(2,"Print cars"),
PRINT_MOTORCYCLES(3, "Print motorcyces"),

private int value;
private String description;

Option(int value, String description) {
    this.value = value;
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value + "-" + description;
}

public static Option createFromInt(int option) throws NoSuchOptionException {
    try {
        return Option.values()[option];
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        throw new NoSuchOptionException("Brak opcji o ID: " + option);
    }
}
```

}

I was just wondering is it corectly locate these enums in two files or exists any more elegant way for example one file with two enums , or nested enums (if something like that at all exists).

Answer (score 2):

At first, I think you don't need the `value` field. Indeed, as shown in `createFromInt`, you refer to enum values with their position (`Option.values()[option]`).

I suggest the following refactoring.

```
enum Option {
  ADD_CAR("Add car"),
  ADD_MOTORCYCLE("Add motorcycle"),
  PRINT_CARS("Print cars"),
  PRINT_MOTORCYCLES("Print motorcycles");

  private String description;

  Option(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return this.ordinal() + "-" + description;
  }

  public static Option getFromIndex(int optionIndex) throws NoSuchOptionException {
    if (optionIndex >= 0 && optionIndex < values().length) {
      return Option.values()[optionIndex];
    }
    throw new NoSuchOptionException("Brak opcji o ID: " + optionIndex);
  }
}
```

I prefer `getFromIndex` because the argument is an index or a *value* and you don't create new instances of the enum.

Comment: You should protect against negative `optionIndex` values in `getFromIndex()`, not just too large values.